# vba collection of shapes

Tags: vba, excel

I want to store buttons in some sort of collection, arraylist,
so that I can add and remove dynamically.

I tried to use Collection but seems it is not the choice, as I got an error when ar.Add() is reached.

*Object doesn't support this property or method.*

```
 Public Sub removeAllFormsWithAdd()
 Dim myshape As Shape
Dim ar As Collection
For Each myshape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If (myshape.FormControlType = xlButtonControl) Then 
    If (myshape.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "name") Then
        ar.Add (myshape)
        Debug.Print "next shape:" & myshape.TextFrame.Characters.Text & "-"
    End If
    End If
    Next myshape
End Sub
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ar.Add()` is not reached as `ar` is `Nothing`. You should initialize it to a `New Collection`.

Other than that, remove the parentheses:

```
ar.Add myshape
```

With the parentheses, you are trying to add to the collection the value of the default property of the shape object, and `Shape` doesn't have a default property.